# Sharing the content on LinkedIn using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sharing, linkedin-api, http-status-code-400

I had integrated the latest [sdks](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#iossdk) of Linkedin for sharing the contents. As it is worked before but now its gives the errors. Please find the below error message.

> Error Domain=LISDKErrorAPIDomain Code=400 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={LISDKAuthErrorAPIResponse=}

Please find the below code which I am using in the application for sharing the contents.

```
- (IBAction)postOnLinkedin:(id)sender {

    if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {

        [self postOnLinedln];
    }

    else {

      [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray 
      arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, 
      LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil]
         state:@"some state" showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES

          successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

              [self postOnLinedln];
          }

          errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            [self showAlert:error.localizedDescription];
          }
      ];
   }
 }

- (void)postOnLinedln {

    NSString *url = @"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";

    NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"comment\":\"Hello\","
                         "\"content\":{ \"title\":\"Title\","
                         "\"description\":\"%@\","
                         "\"submitted-url\":\"\","
                         "\"submitted-image-url\":\"\"},"
                         "\"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\"}}", self.description];

    if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {

        [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] postRequest:url stringBody:payload
                                             success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {

           // do something with response                                                     
          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

             [self showAlert:@"Posted successfully"];                                                         
          });
      }

      error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {

           // do something with error                                                       
           dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

               [self showAlert:apiError.description];
           });
       }];
     }

    else {

        [self showAlert:@"No Valid session Linkdln"];
    }
}
```

As I have also gone through the developer portal of LinkedIn for resolving the issue but not getting any help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not passed the characters in the description field which is more than 256 which mentioned in the [linkedin guideline](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin).

For more information please find the below screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The response tells you that you are not authentificated.

[LinkedIN OAuth API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)

Therefore your problem lies with the authentification call that needs to go first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I thought the process of OUAuth for mobile(iOS) application is not accessary as sdk will do for you, for more information please view the developer section of mobile for iOS(https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk#ios9) and I am follow the same steps according to site but it could not work.

Comment: You missunderstood me. The sdk works. The problem is with your implementation. You didn't register properly or the identifier is mismatching or the shared secret missing. Something like that.

Comment: Thanks, actually I had updated my question and added the authentication process please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your payload and add this.

```
NSString *url = @"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";
    NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"comment\":\"Hello\","
                         "\"content\":{ \"title\":\"Title\","
                         "\"description\":\"hi\","
                         "\"submitted-url\":\"hello\","
                         "\"submitted-image-url\":\"\"},"
                         "\"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\"}}"];
```